# How to load CSV file automatically in Google cloud platform?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am new to GCP. I want to load CSV file automatically in any google cloud platform component like Bigquery, Bigtable etc.. I do not want manually work for loading a file everyday on GCP. I want to handle this manual work automatically by GCP. Please suggest me any scenario so i can load file automatically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 3):

Building on Pentium's solid answer, you also have the option on the following (serverless) conga line:

`GCS -> Cloud Functions -> Dataflow (template) -> BigQuery`

We use this pattern a lot of our projects, and it works beautifully. It's event driven, PB scalable, fully automated and zero-ops.

Comment: can you share more about the Dataflow template. I'd love to give a try.

Comment: https://shinesolutions.com/2017/03/23/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions/

Comment: awesome article! I used appengine's cron feature for this type of task, will give this approach a try as well!

Comment: It is possible to used cloud shell for loading file automatically?? @GrahamPolley

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to watch for [Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) in GCS.
So whenever you upload a file you can have a webhook pinging an URL.

Then you can setup either an App Engine application or Cloud Function to do your import, all this is serverless.

Comment: It is possible to load file automatically using cloud shell??